# R package dependency issues when namespace is not attached

Tags: r, cran

I have always assumed that having a package in the 'Depends' field would automatically also *import* the namespace. However, it seems that in R 2.15, dependencies do not become available until the package is actually *attached* to the searchpath. Is this intended behavior?

The problem appears as follows: Suppose there is a package 'Child' which *Depends*, but does not explicitly *Import* a package called 'Parent' and contains a function that calls out to an object in the namespace of 'Parent'. Then when this function is called without actually attaching 'Child', the function in 'Parent' cannot be found.

Here an example from the manual of the `bigdata` package, but the problem is very widespread:

```
x = matrix(rnorm(50*80),50,80)
beta = c(3,2,1.5,rep(0,77))
y = rnorm(50) + x%*%beta
z1 = bigdata::lasso.stars(x,y)
```

The example fails because lasso.stars depends on 'glmnet' which is not loaded until `bigdata` is attached. The only way to be able to call `lasso.stars` is to actually attach the `bigdata` package:

```
library(bigdata)
z1 = bigdata::lasso.stars(x,y)
```

Now to further complicate things, it seems that this problem is inherited to any 'grandchild' package that *Imports* in this case the lasso.stars function. I have a hard time finding a good example but I am sure they are out there.

Is this a bug? I know that it can be avoided by asking package authors to use Imports instead of Depends, but in practice the majority of the packages on CRAN still use Depends. It seems like the problem is easily avoided if R would automatically import the namespace of any Depends packages into to the child package namespace.

Comment: +1 Great question. It's one I've thought of broaching myself, but have put off, thinking it might be better raised over on R-devel (since I think the R-core members are the only folks who can solve this). They must have discussed it, but I've searched quickly several times and have seen no mention of it, which seems odd...

Comment: @Jeroen, could you please provide the example? When I try `library(xts)`, then the export functions of `zoo` is automatically loaded.

Comment: @kohske the example is in the topic. The `xts` package has a NAMESPACE file in which it manually imports required functions form `zoo`. Therefore it doesn't have the problem I think.

Comment: Do you talk about `random` package? But I cannot find the depends of `bigdata` in the `random` package.

Comment: I changed the wording a bit. Just run the 4 lines in a clean R session and it will fail.

Comment: I imagine this is not a bug. Why not `library(bigdata)`? Is there any reason?

Comment: @kohske -- The problem is that if you write a package that needs a function like `lasso.stars()` from the `bigdata` package, you can't get away with doing that via an `Imports` directive. If you just put `import(bigdata)` in the **NAMESPACE** file, the package will find `lasso.stars()`, but won't be able to use it, because it *won't* find `glmnet()` from the `glmnet` package. So, as a package writer, you are forced to instead use `Depends: bigdata` (which causes both `bigdata` and `glmnet` to be attached to the search path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that are interested, the discussion continues [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-package-dependency-issues-when-namespace-is-not-attached-td4629828.html) on the r-devel mailing list: